# Changing from mediaplayer to soundpool

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've got some code setup that plays 3 sound files in my `/raw/` folder one after the other, using the `android.media.MediaPlayer` object. Two of the 3 sounds are selected at random each time the MediaPlayer is called to play.

However, I've realised this really isn't the best way to do so because the sound clips are so short. I've done a bit of looking at `android.media.SoundPool`. However I'm not really sure how to incorporate `SoundPool` instead of using the `MediaPlayer`. Here's what I've got at the moment.

Any pointers on how I can basically change from using a MediaPlayer to SoundPool would be appreciated.

```
mpButtonOne = MediaPlayer.create(camera_page.this, R.raw.default);

if (mpButtonOne==null){
    //display a Toast message here
    return;
}

mpButtonOne.start();
mpButtonOne.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        int audio = mfile[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS)];
        audioReplayPrimary = audio;
        mpButtonOne.reset();
        mpButtonOne = MediaPlayer.create(camera_page.this, audio);

        if (mpButtonOne==null){
            //display a Toast message here
            return;
        }

        mpButtonOne.start();

        mpButtonOne.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                int audio2 = mfile2[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS2)];
                audioReplaySecondary = audio2;
                mpButtonOne.reset();
                mpButtonOne = MediaPlayer.create(camera_page.this, audio2);

                if (mpButtonOne==null){
                    //display a Toast message here
                    return;
                }
                mpButtonOne.start();

                mpButtonOne.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mpButtonOne.release();
                    }
```

UPDATE

```
    private static SoundPool mSoundPool;
private static AudioManager mAudioManager;
private final int SOUND_CLIPS3 = 5;
private int mfile3[] = new int[SOUND_CLIPS3];
private Random rnd = new Random();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sptest);

    mfile3[0] = R.raw.one;
    mfile3[1] = R.raw.two;
    mfile3[2] = R.raw.three;
    mfile3[3] = R.raw.four;
    mfile3[4] = R.raw.five;

    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


        Button spTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSp);
    spTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int audioPre = mfile3[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS3)];
            int sound1 = mSoundPool.load(sptestclass.this, audioPre, 1);
            mSoundPool.play(sound1, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);

    }
    });
```

Comment: Did you get playing sound samples one after each other working using the SoundPool class? It seems like it does not have a listener for it like MediaPlayer does. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `android.media.SoundPool` object like this:

```
import android.media.SoundPool;
//...

//inside your class:
//define: mContext = <your context>
private static SoundPool mSoundPool;
private static AudioManager mAudioManager;

//inside your method:
mSoundPool = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

int sound1 = mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.sound1, 1); //<context, soundId, priority>
int sound2 = mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.sound2, 1); //<context, soundId, priority>
int sound3 = mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.sound3, 1); //<context, soundId, priority>

//play a sound:
mSoundPool.play(sound1, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);//soundId (from load()), volLeft, volRight, priority, loop(boolean), playbackRate


//register a callback for onLoad...:
mSoundPool1.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
        //call .play() for the next sound
    }
});


//if you want to explicitly stop the sound:
mSoundPool.stop(sound1);
```

Comment: This worked however it wasn't randomly playing the sounds anymore, I've updated it with what I think would work however I get no audio at all. I have to have the `int audioPre = mfile3[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS3)];` within the `onClick` so that it generates a new random file to play out of the `mfile3` list every time. Any ideas why I'm getting no audio now? Please bare in mind that it played audio whilst `int audioPre = mfile3[rnd.nextInt(SOUND_CLIPS3)];` was outside of the `onClick` however it just didn't randomise anymore.

Comment: Perhaps the lack of sound means that the rnd.nextInt is returning a value that is not valid for the range of sounds in your resources.. perhaps you can use logs/debugging to see what the difference is between those 2 scenarios. ( using Log.d("TAG","info"); )